# Update 10000 records at a time

Tags: oracle, sql-update

I want to update 10000 records at a time.This is the query that I'm using

```
UPDATE CUSTOMERS SET CUST_HOME_PHONE = 
REGEXP_REPLACE(CUST_HOME_PHONE,'([0-9]{3})([0-9]{3})([0-9]{4})', '(\1)-\2-\3',1,0 )
where cust_id in (10000 cust id);
```

However, the problem is that using IN condition I can't enter more than 1000 records because that's the limit of IN condition. Please let me know the solution.

Comment: how you obtain thr 1000 cust id?

Comment: @scaisEdge... I have cust id's with me...instead of running 10 times update statement I want that type of query that can update the records at once.

Comment: This is an annoying limitation. You can do `where (cust_id in (first 1000 cust id) or cust_id in (second 1000 cust id) …)`. It's beyong me why Oracle can't drop the limit and do the same under the hood.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the 10000 values in a temporary table and then do a select where id in (select id from temptable)